# Secure remote access to the GIT server

Tags: git, ssh, localhost

I have a situation like the attached drawing. I would like to be able to work fully with GIT (push, pull, etc.) from computer number 1 where I have a virtual machine with Linux. This computer is connected to the Internet as computer no. 2. Computer no. 2 has a GIT server connected via the local network, which is located on computer 3. I would like to be able to work safely between computers no. 1 and 3. Do I need to use some tunneling?
[image: My problem]

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "safely". Using encrypted communications should prevent eavesdropping or tampering, but obviously won't prevent them from disconnecting you if they want to DoS you. Not really a programming question anyway.

Comment: Perhaps I will come to the word 'safety' in the last step. However, at this point, I don't know how to make this connection. Do you have any suggestion?